# I have two gifs that are renamed as a jpg. One works but one doesn't. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: jpeg, gif

So here are the two links to both of em:

The one that works: https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_z8wtl/styles/profileIcon_3fzia0xi5bk51.jpg?width=256&height=256&crop=256:256,smart&frame=1&s=ee026566e22bbf6be1a9593f4e8658a81beca03c

The one that doesn't work: https://styles.redditmedia.com/t5_z8wtl/styles/profileIcon_kx6k46y3fbk51.jpg?width=256&height=256&crop=256:256,smart&frame=1&s=d8f717214b28d648fb33f93eecca9e6242b11ae6

Answer (score 0):

What you mean `works` ? Second one hase only one frame, so it is not animated.

Use [this tool](https://ezgif.com/split) to analyze.